# Making an R histogram plot from a saved hist() call

Tags: r, plot, histogram

In R, one can do

```
x <- rnorm(100, 0, 1) # generate some fake data
hgram <- hist(x, plot=F)
plot(hgram$mids, hgram$counts)
```

One can further specify a plot type, such as 'h' or 's'. However, these don't really come out looking like a proper histogram. How can one make a nice looking histogram this way?

Comment: Just `plot(hgram)`.

Comment: `hist` function itself presents a format that can be drawn with `plot` function. If you want to manipulate and build your own histogram you will need the arguments you are using, but this is going to be trickier.

Comment: `hist(x)` or `ggplot2::qplot(x, bins = 9)`

Comment: You could also plot with `highcharter` package, doing something like this: `hgram %>% hchart()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought to add my inputs about making decent looking histograms in R (using your "x" from your question).

Using Base R

```
# histogram with colors and labels
hist(x, main = "Histogram of Fake Data", xlab = paste("x (units of measure)"), border = "blue", col = "green", prob = TRUE)
# add density
lines(density(x)) 
# add red line at 95th percentile
abline(v = quantile(x, .95), col = "red")
```

Using Plotly

```
install.packages("plotly")
library(plotly)
# basic Plotly histogram
plot_ly(x = x, type = "histogram")
```

The plotly result should open in a browser window with a variety of interactive controls.  More plotly capabilities are available on their website at: 
https://plot.ly/r/histograms/#normalized-histogram